Azure DevOps - Not able to add bug stories to test suites
When creating a new test plan in ADO and adding a static test suite, Im receiving an error while trying to add a bug story as an existing test case.  The error message is “You should select at least one work item belonging to Microsoft.TestCaseCategory”.  Is there a way to configure bug stories to belong TestCaseCategory, or is there a work around to add bugs to a test suite without having to add an additional test case?
I'm expecting to be able to add bugs stories to test plans without having to create a separate test case linked to the bug.
